# Goto a specific Address in C

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, goto, pointer-address

How can I JMP to a specific address in C?

I want to use

```
goto 0x10080000
```

This is not working, is there other way I can change the address of Program Counter??

Comment: If you know the address, you could always say `asm("jmp 0x10080000")`...

Answer (score 11):

You can *cast* the address to a function pointer and then jump into:

```
((void (*)(void))0x10008000)();
```

To make it a bit more clear:

```
typedef void (*func_t)(void);
...
((func_t)0x10008000)();
```

**But** this is a function, the compiler will emit a branch instruction that expect to return (then is up to you to make your function return or not).
Also notice that the compiler will produce a code that expect to find a C function at the given address, about how the function arguments are given and returned.

If you need to emit a branch instruction without return you need to use inline assembly.

Answer (score 10):

In GCC you can use [computed goto](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). I didn't try it myself, but it should work like this:

```
void *address = 0x10080000;
...
goto *address;
```

Answer (score 3):

Inline assembly instruction should work too:

`asm("jump 0x10080000");`